# SQL combining declared string variables on the left side of the equals sign

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to combine two declared string variables on the left side of the equals sign, this will enable me to choose what my variable will be called. Is this possible? I think I can find a work round for what I want to do, but the following code would be a lot cleaner.

This is what I have so far but it is not working:

```
DECLARE @operate VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @date5 VARCHAR(6)
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(2)
SET @month=5
SET @operate='(@date' +@month+ '=10)'
EXEC(@operate)
PRINT(@date5)
```

Comment: You cannot use exec() like that to evaluate a string, use sp_executeSQL & parameters.  You should explain more fully what you want to accomplish.

Comment: requirement is not clear

Comment: An [MCVE](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) would really help here.  Show us the starting values and the required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you ask for, though I can't help but feel its not the best way of working, and is probably just storing up maintenance headaches for the future. Its hard to suggest alternatives without more information of the context though. Consider creating a question about the higher level problem and ways to approach it. I suspect there would be an easier way storing data in a table perhaps?

Its making the assumption that all the @dateX variables are varchar(6):

```
DECLARE @operate NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @date5 VARCHAR(6)
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(2)
SET @month=5
SET @operate=N'set @date' + @month + '=10'
SET @params=N'@date' + @month + ' varchar(6) OUTPUT'
exec master.dbo.sp_ExecuteSQL @operate, @params, @date5=@date5 output
PRINT(@date5)
```